# How to detect the highlight point of a pyramid top view image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

As you can see in the sample image, it's a surface image capture by SEM. What I want to do is to detect the peak of each pyramid as accurate as possible.

[image: origin]

I have tried corner detection method and turn out the peak point is not recognize as corner. Are there any other methods good at such task?

[image: corner]

```py
params = dict(maxCorners=500,
              qualityLevel=0.01,
              minDistance=5,
              blockSize=10,
              useHarrisDetector=False)
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(sharp_img, **params)
```

Comment: can you vary the lighting? make it come from each of several directions in turn, and take pictures? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_stereo -- from the 3D data, it's trivial to find local maxima having whatever qualities you need. -- if that approach isn't possible, you could try simple `cv::matchTemplate`, using a template of one of those pyramid tips. the tips all look the same, right?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz unfortunately only 1 photo is taken for each sample. Template matching would be worth to try, thank you.

Comment: I can achieve this with some "score" thresholds that need adjusting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qlNd.png

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That looks pretty good. Can you write an answer to share your receip? I have try to use threshold on a blured image and the result is not as good as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach: template matching, using a patch of a pyramid's tip.

I'm judging (eyeballing) the results by the [number of false positives and false negatives, the balance of which can be adjusted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) with a threshold on the scores from template matching.

I used the average of several pyramid tips, sized 40x40 ("radius" 20), but a template from just one should suffice. Either take a crop with a photo editor or write the code for selecting some points, collecting and averaging the crops.

I tried `fastNlMeansDenoising`. It has no clear benefit. The template matching already is a kind of lowpass filter.

I also undid the gamma-mapping on the entire input image. Just `(im * np.float32(1/255)) ** 2.2`. That has a clear benefit to the results.

I also applied a Sobel/Scharr filter. It appears to give better results. I composed the response in X and Y direction and the magnitude into a 3-channel image for further processing.

[image: Scharr composite]

Here's the tip:

[image: tip]

You could also involve `copyMakeBorder` to get tips that are near the edges of the image... since there's less image content there, you may not get any hits there anyway.

Anyway, the core of the code is this:

```
scores = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, template, cv.TM_CCOEFF)
```

Now you need to scrape local maxima from that. This is non-maxima suppression:

```
localmax = cv.dilate(scores, None, iterations=radius) # or 2*radius
localmax = (scores == localmax)

levelmask = (scores >= 200)

candidates = levelmask & localmax

(nlabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(candidates.astype(np.uint8), connectivity=8)
print(nlabels-1, "found")
```

The `centroids` give you the top left corner of each matching instance of the template. Add `(radius, radius)` to get the center of the template.

The rest is just drawing:

```
for label, pt in zip(range(1, nlabels), centroids[1:]):
    ipt = pt.round().astype(int)
    bestscore = scores[labels == label].max()
    ...
```

Here are the results. I see at least one false positive, and false negatives too, but those pyramids are smaller than the patch radius.

This could be improved by testing template matching scores on both the Scharr-filtered (gradients) and the straight input (levels).

[image: results]

Comment: I do learn a lot of useful tricks from your answer, thank you! Is it a common trick to use template with dialate for non-maxima suppression.  Do I need to create a kernel for `cv.dialate` or the default 3x3 rect is enough for this?

Comment: this formulation of NMS works on anything that is smooth and has extrema (minima: erode), not just scores from template matching. passing `None` for the kernel assumes a 3x3 box kernel. you could use other shapes, say a circle, but that's a minor detail and doesn't really change the results here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried very very simple way:
"It looks like that nearer to top of pyramid be brighter, so... can't climb the pyramid from each pixel position?"

I implemented in C++ very very straightforwardly(:not good code).

```cpp
//Start from (x,y) --> move to brighter position.
//When reached to local brightest position, vote to the position.
void Work(
    int x, int y,  //Start position
    const cv::Mat &ProcTgtImg, //Gray Scale Pyramids image
    cv::Mat &FootPrintBuff, //This is a storage to avoid duplicate work.
    cv::Mat &Votes, //Voting Buffer
    int r   //local region size(radius)
)
{
    static std::vector< cv::Vec2i > Route;  //Why "static" is, to reduce memory allocation cost.

    auto UpdateWork = [&]( cv::Vec2i ResultPos )->void{
        for( const auto &P : Route ){   FootPrintBuff.at<cv::Vec2i>( P[1],P[0] ) = ResultPos;   }
        ++Votes.at<unsigned short>( ResultPos[1], ResultPos[0] );
    };

    Route.clear();
    while( true )
    {
        Route.emplace_back( x,y );

        {//If current position(x,y) is already processed...
            const auto &FP = FootPrintBuff.at<cv::Vec2i>(y,x);
            if( FP[0] >= 0 )
            {
                UpdateWork( FP );
                return;
            }
        }

        //Find the position has local max pixel value
        cv::Vec2i MaxValPos(x,y);
        {// * Perhaps circle would be better for the shape of the region, but square is used here for simplicity.
            int top = std::max( 0, y-r );
            int bottom = std::min( ProcTgtImg.rows-1, y+r );
            int left = std::max( 0, x-r );
            int right = std::min( ProcTgtImg.cols-1, x+r );
        
            unsigned char MaxVal = 0;
            for( int yy=top; yy<=bottom; ++yy )
            {
                const unsigned char *p = ProcTgtImg.ptr<unsigned char>( yy, left );
                for( int xx=left; xx<=right; ++xx, ++p )
                {
                    if( MaxVal < *p )
                    {
                        MaxVal = *p;
                        MaxValPos = cv::Vec2i(xx,yy);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //If current position has local max value, Vote to current position.
        if( x==MaxValPos[0] && y==MaxValPos[1] )
        {
            UpdateWork( MaxValPos );
            return;
        }
        //Change the current position to the local max position.
        x = MaxValPos[0];
        y = MaxValPos[1];
    }
}

//
int main()
{
    //Load image as GrayScale
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread( "Pyramids.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( SrcImg.empty() )return 0;
    cv::imshow( "SrcImg", SrcImg );
    
    //Process
    cv::Mat Votes = cv::Mat::zeros( SrcImg.size(), CV_16U );
    {
        cv::Mat ProcTgtImg;
        cv::medianBlur( SrcImg, ProcTgtImg, 5 );

        cv::Mat FootPrintBuff( SrcImg.size(), CV_32SC2 );
        FootPrintBuff = cv::Scalar(-1,-1);

        for( int y=0; y<ProcTgtImg.rows; ++y )
        {
            for( int x=0; x<ProcTgtImg.cols; ++x )
            {
                Work( x,y, ProcTgtImg, FootPrintBuff, Votes, 32 );
            }
        }
    }

    {//Show Result
        cv::Mat Visualize( SrcImg.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        cv::cvtColor( SrcImg, Visualize, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
        Visualize *= 0.45;

        double MaxVal;  //Max Vote value is just used to change the draw circle size
        cv::minMaxLoc( Votes, NULL, &MaxVal );

        for( int y=0; y<Votes.rows; ++y )
        {
            const unsigned short *v = Votes.ptr<unsigned short>(y);
            for( int x=0; x<Votes.cols; ++x, ++v )
            {
                if( *v )
                {   cv::circle( Visualize, cv::Point(x,y), 2+int(10*(*v)/MaxVal), cv::Scalar(64,64,255), 2 );   }
            }
        }
        cv::imshow( "Visualize", Visualize );
    }
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

This is result.
I can not say this result is very good, but some tops found.
Larger circle indicate more votes.
[image]

Comment: Yes, this simple way may generate false positives at the image border, in principle.

Comment: It looks good. Currently I am using `peak_local_max` from `skimage` to find peaks in a blured image which is similar to what you does. I have the same false positives issue at the edge and this could be alleviated by filtering with threshold and using non local mean to smooth the image.